# Error: interface not supported. Delphi 10.2 Tókio

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10, embarcadero

Erro ao tentar salvar a janela de tools=> options do Delphi 10.2

Já tentei reinstalar a imagem da IDE para ver ser reselveria.
Só consigo fechar a janela se "Cancelar" a operação.

Alguém tem uma dica ou solução para o erro?

ERROR: **interface not supported.**

[image: interface not supported.]

Answer (score 0):

amigo...
creio que você resolveria isso reparando o seu delphi. Porém, se fizer isso creio que terá que instalar os componentes novamente..
mas dá uma olhada nisso aqui, acho que te ajudará:
[Using the -r command line switch to fix start up errors in the IDE](http://support.embarcadero.com/article/42597)

Comment: Obrigado @Cleyton Alves, já foi de grande ajuda, desinstalou os componentes, mas é melhor do que precisar reinstalar e ou modificar pelo Instalador. Vou ver melhor a documentação para ver as possibilidades.

Comment: ahh... que legal que te ajudou!